# Why won't this function work for my program. (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm doing a baseball program for a class project. And I almost have it complete, but it's giving me a syntax error. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I'm using two functions to return a value for different type of baseball tickets to the button that calculates them.

Here are the instructions 
1.)User selects whether to purchase season tickets or single-game tickets

2.) User enters the number of tickets needed and the type of seats based on whether they selected season single-game tickets.

3.) User clicks the Compute Ticket Cost Button to display final cost

4.) User clicks the Clear Form button to clear the response

I just can't figure out what I did wrong. I know it's something stupid that i'm doing.

the errors are happening inside the btnCompute sub routine. 
with syntax erros on SingleGameCost() and SeasonalCost() line 114 and 118

```
Public Class Form1
'Global Variables

Dim intTicketChoice As Integer
Dim seatType As Integer
Dim ticketNum As Integer








Private Sub cboTicketType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboTicketType.SelectedIndexChanged



    intTicketChoice = Me.cboTicketType.SelectedIndex
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Clear()

    Select Case intTicketChoice

        Case 0
            SingleGame()

        Case 1
            Seasonal()


    End Select

    'Make Items visible

    Me.lblCostDisplay.Visible = True
    Me.lblSeats.Visible = True
    Me.lblTickets.Visible = True
    Me.lstSeatType.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Visible = True
    Me.btnClear.Visible = True
    Me.btnCompute.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub SingleGame()





    'Add List Items

    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $55")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $35")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Upper Deck Seats $25")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Standing Room Only $15")

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $55" Then
        seatType = 0
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $35" Then
        seatType = 1
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Upper Deck Seats $25" Then
        seatType = 2
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Standing Room Only $15" Then
        seatType = 3
    End If


End Sub



Private Sub Seasonal()





    'Add List Items
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $2500")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $1500")


    'Price Items for Single Games
    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $2500" Then
        seatType = 4
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $1500" Then
        seatType = 5
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click



    intTicketChoice = Me.cboTicketType.SelectedIndex

    If intTicketChoice = 0 Then
        SingleGameCost()
    End If

    If intTicketChoice = 1 Then
        SeasonalCost()

    End If


    'try and catch number textbox

    Try
        ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketNum.Text)
    Catch Exception As FormatException
        MsgBox("Number of tickets must be numeric")
        Return

    End Try

    'display cost of tickets

    Me.lblCostDisplay.Text = "The total cost of tickets purchased: " & totalCost.ToString("C")


End Sub

Private Function SingleGameCost(ByVal seatType As Integer, ByRef ticketNum As Integer, ByRef cost As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim totalCost As Decimal


    ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTicketNum.Text)

    'Price Items for Single Games

    If seatType = 0 Then
        cost = 55D
    End If


    If seatType = 1 Then
        cost = 35D
    End If


    If seatType = 2 Then
        cost = 25D
    End If

    If seatType = 3 Then
        cost = 15D
    End If

    totalCost = ticketNum * cost
    Return totalCost


End Function
Private Function SeasonalCost(ByVal seatType As Integer, ByRef ticketNum As Integer, ByRef cost As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim totalCost As Decimal



    ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTicketNum.Text)

    If seatType = 4 Then
        cost = 2500D
    End If

    If seatType = 5 Then
        cost = 1500D
    End If

    totalCost = cost * ticketNum
    Return totalCost



End Function
```

End Class

kthe error is happening here

```
If intTicketChoice = 0 Then
        SingleGameCost()
    End If

    If intTicketChoice = 1 Then
        SeasonalCost()

    End If
```

with the singlegamecost() function and the seasonacost() function

Comment: the errors are happening inside the btnCompute sub routine.

Comment: with syntax erros on SingleGameCost() and SeasonalCost()

Comment: What line gives the syntax error ? This alone whould help a lot.

Comment: sorry about that, it's lines 114 and 118

Answer (score 3):

I just quickly looked over this, and it seems you're called SingleGameCost() and
SeasonalCost() without any arguments, but you defined the function with some.

```
`Private Function SingleGameCost(ByVal seatType As Integer, ByRef ticketNum As Integer, ByRef cost As Decimal)`
```

Shouldn't you be supplying the arguments?

```
 dim seat as integer = 1
 dim ticketNum as integer = 1
 dim cost as decimal = 12.00
 SingleGameCost(seat, ticketNum, cost)
```

Comment: Spot on. @Josh Tha CreativeOne, are you doing this within an IDE like Visual Studio? You should receive a fairly obvious error of `Argument not specified for parameter 'cost' of 'Private Function SingleGameCost(seatType As Integer, ByRef ticketNum As Integer, ByRef cost As Decimal) As Decimal`

Comment: I just didn't understand the error. I guess I should have stated that also. And yes i'm using visual studio. I'm just a n00b with all of this.

Comment: Thanks this worked, yes I got that error. I just had no clue what it meant. I'm still a n00b with all of this.

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head, if it's the return , change it to End Sub since this is not a function but a sub. But I can't tell if I don't know which line gives the error.

Comment: Could you tell us which line is this.. I'm not going to count all lines one by one...

Comment: If intTicketChoice = 0 Then
            SingleGameCost()
        End If

        If intTicketChoice = 1 Then
            SeasonalCost()

        End If

Comment: i'm getting an error on the functions: SingleGameCost() and SeasonalCost()